# What type of epithelium are the pancreatic Islets of Langerhans?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, human-anatomy, histology

The human pancreas contains exocrine acinus cells (simple cuboidal epithelium) and Islets of Langerhans. Despite looking online I cannot identify what type of epithelium the Islets of Langerhans conform to (e.g., cuboidal, columnar, squamous). I'm confident it is not squamous due to the shape of the cells, but the distinction between cuboidal and columnar seems equivocal here.

[image: Pancreas histology]

Answer (score 2):

I think the image you've attached lacks clarity. If you see the image below, you could say that the epithelium is cuboidal with central rounded nucleus.

[image: A clearer image]

Unlike the oval nuclei of columnar epithelium, rounded nucleus suggests that they are cuboidal in shape.

The image is from https://webpath.med.utah.edu/HISTHTML/NORMAL/NORM010.html

Comment: Welcome. Can you add sources to your claim and mention where the image was extracted from?

Comment: It is a fact that cellular morphology as well as the shape of nucleus will be taken into account when describing a cell as columnar or cuboidal. Due to the lack of clarity in the OPs image, I am showing this image as it is clearer to understand.